# C# Multithreading in for loop, how to check exit of all threads

Tags: c#

I'm trying to call a method through a Thread object, here's the code

```
for (int i = 0; i < 255; i++)
{
    Thread t = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(Pinger.Ping));
    t.Start(i.ToString());      
}
```

how can I check if every thread has finished?

Comment: Turn `Thread`s into `Task`s and then `WaitAll`/`WhenAll`

Comment: Another way is to use *PLinq* with `ForAll`

Comment: I'd rather to use `Thread` if possible, if not i'll use your solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, try to avoid creating Threads like that because your application it will turn in a chaos (memory, thread allocation) and managing Threads manually can be tricky.

It's recommended to use a Thread Pool that manages/reuses threads for you.

Please read this official documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/the-managed-thread-pool

Answering your question, it should be something like this:
(I have not tested the code)

```
var myTasks = new List<Task>();
for (int i = 0; i < 255; i++)
{
    myTasks.add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Pinger.Ping(parameters...)));
}

Tasks.WhenAll(myTasks);
```

Comment: And what about parameters of method `Pinger.Ping`

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `Join()` on all the `Theads` you create.

```
List<Thread> threads = new List<Thread>();
for (int i = 0; i < 255; i++)
{
    Thread t = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(Pinger.Ping));
    threads.Add(t);
    t.Start(i.ToString());      
}

for (int i = 0; i < 255; i++)
   threads[i].Join();
```